# Mongoid identity_map and memory usage, memory leaks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, memory-leaks, mongoid

When I executing query

```
 Mymodel.all.each do |model|
# ..do something  
end
```

It uses allot of memory and amount of used memory increases at all the time and at the and it crashes. I found out that to fix it I need to disable  identity_map but when I adding to my `mongoid.yml` file `identity_map_enabled: false` I am getting error

```
Invalid configuration option: identity_map_enabled.
Summary:
  A invalid configuration option was provided in your mongoid.yml, or a typo is potentially present. The valid configuration options are: :include_root_in_json, :include_type_for_serialization, :preload_models, :raise_not_found_error, :scope_overwrite_exception, :duplicate_fields_exception, :use_activesupport_time_zone, :use_utc.
Resolution:
  Remove the invalid option or fix the typo. If you were expecting the option to be there, please consult the following page with repect to Mongoid's configuration:
```

> `I am using Rails 4 and Mongoid 4, Mymodel.all.count => 3202400`

How can I fix it or maybe some one know other way to reduce amount of memory used during executing query .all.each ..? 
Thank you very much for the help!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't the identity map, I don't think Mongoid4 even has an identity map built in, hence the configuration error when you try to turn it off. Your problem is that you're using `all`. When you do this:

```
Mymodel.all.each
```

Mongoid will attempt to instantiate every single document in the `db.mymodels` collection as a `Mymodel` instance before it starts iterating. You say that you have about 3.2 million documents in the collection, that means that Mongoid will try to create 3.2 million model instances before it tries to iterate. Presumably you don't have enough memory to handle that many objects.

Your `Mymodel.all.count` works fine because that just sends a simple `count` call into the database and returns a number, it won't instantiate any models at all.

The solution is to not use `all` (and preferably forget that it exists). Depending on what "do something" does, you could:

1. Page through all the models so that you're only working with a reasonable number of them at a time.
2. Push the logic into the database using `mapReduce` or the aggregation framework.

Whenever you're working with real data (i.e. something other than a trivially small database), you should push as much work as possible into the database because databases are built to manage and manipulate big piles of data.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. ` I tried Mymodel.each do ` without `all` it uses same large amount of mamory and crushes at the end.  Do you mind to show me example how to implement `Mymodel.each do` via mapReduce in Mongoid please!!!

Comment: Doing `Mymodel.each` will also load them all. Like I said, you need to translate your "do something" step into a form that MongoDB will understand before you can use `mapReduce` or the aggregation framework.

Answer (score 1):

I started with something just like you by doing loop through millions of record and the memory just keep increasing.

Original code:

```
@portal.listings.each do |listing|
  listing.do_something
end
```

I've gone through many forum answers and I tried them out.

**1st attempt**: I try to use the combination of `WeakRef` and `GC.start` but no luck, I fail.

**2nd attempt**: Adding `listing = nil` to the first attempt, and still fail.

**Success Attempt**:

```
@start_date  = 10.years.ago
@end_date = 1.day.ago

while @start_date < @end_date
  @portal.listings.where(created_at: @start_date..@start_date.next_month).each do |listing|
    listing.do_something
  end

  @start_date = @start_date.next_month
end
```

**Conclusion**

> All the memory allocated for the record will never be released during
>   the query request. Therefore, trying with small number of record every
>   request does the job, and memory is in good condition since it will be
>   released after each request.